# Copy+Paste not working in terminal VPS, Debian 8 install

Tags: terminal, clipboard, vps

I'm trying to install/set up some VPS servers. But copying and pasting commands into the terminal is not working during the install.

According to Google searches, there are many suggestions, such as using  press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>. But none are working and you can't use a mouse during the online VPS install.
Due to near blindness, it is very difficult for me to type lengthy commands, without error.   Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't using `Ctrl`+`V` not `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`V` (the latter being the correct one - you say you are a newbie.

Comment: Nope.  Unfortunately,  'Ctrl+Shift+V' does NOT work in terminal, at least on Debian 8 nor 9, on online VPS.  I've tried 2 VPS services, Ramnode and Vultr.    Niether have any working means of copy-paste that I can find.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself.   Online VPS do NOT allow any copy-paste!  (at least none I spoke with).  However, you can use an app called 'PuTTy', for SSH, and can use copy-paste through it via right mouse click.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  If they don't allow copy and paste how does it work through putty?  Are you sure you haven't been using putty the whole time?  By default putty doesn't allow ctrl+v but defaults to right click for paste.

Comment: @ – Jesse_b:   No, the Online VPSs (at least the ones i use) have their own GUI system, that does not allow copy-paste from Windows.   But using a 3rd party app like PuTTy solves the problem.

Comment: You should mention that in your question then and what application they are using.  I have used several cloud servers and have always had to use my own application for ssh.